# function only runs when alert() is placed inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why is that when i give alert inside the jquery block it runs other wise it doesn't show any output?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
(function map() {
var test = document.createElement('script'); 
    test.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    test.async = true;
test.src = 'myjsfile.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(test, s);
});
  </script>
```

I am trying to create a plugin and the script calls the myjsfile.js and will execute the functions inside it only is if i add alert() inside the above code.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can debug it?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Are you calling the function anywhere?  Why are there parentheses around it?

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i have added jquery functions inside myjsfile.js

Comment: Check your browser's error console and see if you see any errors.  If not, set breakpoints on your code and figure out what is being called, and not being called.  This is basic debugging that you need to do before anyone can help you.

Comment: @ brad i have already done that... there isn't any error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code that you show is the first script tag on the document, I could see this maybe causing a problem:

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(test, s);
```

Why not append it directly to the head or body? More straightforward, in my opinion.

```
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
 || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(test);
```

Also, you may not be getting any output because you aren't actually calling your function. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function map() {
        // Your code here
    })(); // Add () to call your function

    // Or, just call it the old fashioned way when you're done.
    map();
</script>
```

One other thing to watch out for, `map` is already a function within jQuery, so be cautious with your name spaces and how you try to call your function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're trying to create a function for execution later or a self executing function.

If you're trying to do a self executing function here is the syntax:

```
(function () {
    alert("hello");
})();
```

If you're trying to create a function for later execution:

```
function myfunction() {
    alert("hello");
}

myfunction();// This is the "later" execution
```

Hope this helps!